# How does option overwriting work with logrotate?

Tags: linux, logrotate

From the manual:

> Each configuration file can set global options (local definitions override global ones, and later definitions override earlier ones) and specify logfiles to rotate.

If I understand the definition correctly, `/path2/dir1/.log` options set from the first block will be overwritten by the end block settings. There are a number of dirs that are in `/path2/` and I don't want to write them out individually.

```
/path1/*/*.log 
/path2/*/*.log 
/path3/*/*.log 
/path4/*/*.log 
/path5/*/*.log
{
    size 100k
    rotate 10
    compress
    dateext
    postrotate
        service rsyslog restart >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
 } 
 /path3/dir1/*.log
 {
    size 200k
    rotate 50
    compress
    dateext
    postrotate
        service rsyslog restart >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript 
 }
```

When running test I don't trust my understanding. It seems that in this test that `dir1` would have been handled by the first set of options and then again with the 2nd set of options.

```
logrotate -d mylogconf 2>&1 | less

reading config file mylogconf
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 3 logs

rotating pattern: /path1/*/*.txt
 after 1 days (360 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.

rotating pattern: /path2/*/*.txt
/path3/*/*.txt
 153600 bytes (40 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.

rotating pattern: /path3/dir1/*.txt
 204800 bytes (50 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
```

If I am correct, then I think my conf file needs to look something like this:

```
/path1/*/*.log
/path2/*/*.log
/path3/dir2/*.log
/path3/dir3/*.log
/path3/dir4/*.log
{
    size 100k
    rotate 4
}
/path3/dir1/*.log
{
   size 200k
   rotate 50
}
```

Comment: You seem to initially specify `dir1` as living in `/path2`, but later it's in `/path3`.  This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Updated for consistency, thank you.